# Having trouble creating a safe way for users to update their data

Tags: php, database, mysqli, authentication

I am making a way for users to edit their data. My first way I did it worked, but then I remembered that it is very insecure and that I should never insert data directly into the database; at least that's what I was told. I try to make it more secure by doing the VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) thing so that the data is not directly going in, which seemed to work fine in my registration page (which I can include if you want).

To start, here is my original update data page that worked fine but it does not use the (?,?,?,?,?) method:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $userid=$_SESSION['userid'];
    $skype=$_POST['skype'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $region=$_POST['region'];
    $crank=$_POST['league1'];
    $drank=$_POST['league2'];
        if(empty($skype) || empty($email) || empty($crank) || empty($drank) || empty($region))
        {
            echo "Cannot leave any field blank";
        }       
        else
        {   
            $host= "localhost";
            $dbname = "boost";
            $user = "root";
            $pwd = "";
            $port=3306; 

            try
            {
                $mysqli= new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $dbname,$port);
                if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
                die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
            }
            $query = "UPDATE usertable SET SkypeID = '$skype', Email = '$email', Region = '$region', CRank = '$crank', DRank = '$drank' WHERE UserID = '$userid'";
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_param("sssss",$skype,$email,$region,$crank,$drank); 
            $stmt->execute();
            $iLastInsertId=$mysqli->insert_id; 
            header('Location: http://localhost/Boost/account.php');
            $stmt->close(); 
            $mysqli->close();
        } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { 
        throw $e; 
    } 
  }
}
```

Here is what I tried to do to make it more secure but this doesn't seem to work. Specifically the `$query = "UPDATE usertable SET usertable(SkypeID,Email,Region,CRank,DRank) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) WHERE UserID = '$userid'";` seems to be the issue, though the syntax looks fine to me

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $userid=$_SESSION['userid'];
    $skype=$_POST['skype'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $region=$_POST['region'];
    $crank=$_POST['league1'];
    $drank=$_POST['league2'];
        if(empty($skype) || empty($email) || empty($crank) || empty($drank) || empty($region))
        {
            echo "Cannot leave any field blank";
        }       
        else
        {   
            $host= "localhost";
            $dbname = "boost";
            $user = "root";
            $pwd = "";
            $port=3306; 

            try
            {
                $mysqli= new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $dbname,$port);
                if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
                die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
            }
            $query = "UPDATE usertable SET usertable(SkypeID,Email,Region,CRank,DRank) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) WHERE UserID = '$userid'";
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_param("sssss",$skype,$email,$region,$crank,$drank); 
            $stmt->execute();
            $iLastInsertId=$mysqli->insert_id; 
            header('Location: http://localhost/Boost/account.php');
            $stmt->close(); 
            $mysqli->close();
        } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { 
        throw $e; 
    } 
  }
}
```

So I am not sure what the problem is. In my experience with PHP, the syntax should be fine but I must be missing something.

Comment: What database are you using? That SQL update values syntax is unusual. Are you sure it works? Why change from the previous, more traditional syntax?

Comment: Try `UPDATE usertable SET SkypeID = ?,Email = ?,Region = ?,CRank = ?,DRank = ? WHERE UserID = '$userid'`

Comment: Do you get any error message? Usually those are helpful in understanding the error.

Comment: @Matt Thank you, that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple actually, you went from

```
$query = "UPDATE usertable SET SkypeID = '$skype', Email = '$email', Region = '$region', CRank = '$crank', DRank = '$drank' WHERE UserID = '$userid'";
```

TO

```
$query = "UPDATE usertable SET usertable(SkypeID,Email,Region,CRank,DRank) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) WHERE UserID = '$userid'";
```

It appears you confused an INSERT statement vs. an UPDATE statement when rewriting so to fix you simply use your old statement with the new style...

```
$query = "UPDATE usertable SET SkypeID = ?, Email = ?, Region = ?, CRank = ?, DRank = ? WHERE UserID = $userid";
```

Comment: Oh your right. I thought they would be the same. I changed it to that. However, when I changed the code I got an error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Duplicate entry '?' for key 'Email''

Comment: Nevermind, @Matt 's code worked. Oddly enough I guess (') should not be there? I don't even know anymore

Comment: Correct no quotes, I've edited my answer to reflect the updated values (hacky copy & paste job from your original script on my part I apologize).